# meanio crashed with Error: Cannot find module 'connect-multiparty'

Tags: javascript, mean.io

I got the error like this while running meanio app using grunt

```
/home/me/project/myapp/node_modules/meanio/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'connect-multiparty'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Module.module.exports (/home/me/project/myapp/packages/contrib/upload/server/routes/meanUpload.js:6:21)
    at /home/me/project/myapp/node_modules/meanio/lib/mean.js:286:20
    at /home/me/project/myapp/node_modules/meanio/lib/util.js:21:7
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at walk (/home/me/project/myapp/node_modules/meanio/lib/util.js:16:25)
    at /home/me/project/myapp/node_modules/meanio/lib/util.js:23:7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error might be because of upload package in packages/contrib/upload. In that case just reinstall using mean install command

```
mean install upload
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the package.json file of the mentioned package by the error and add the missing module in the dependencies item:

```
"dependencies": {
    "connect-multiparty": "latest",
    ....
},
```

Then, run `npm install` in the package's folder